# How to remove the highest number of consecutive zeros in the string Python - no imports

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I would like to do is read in a binary string consisting of only zeros and ones.
Something like that:

> **input**
> 1001101000110

I then need to find the highest number of only zeros

> 1001101**000**110 --> biggest number of consecutive zeros
> remove the zeros
> 1001101110

And then also ouput the result as a decimal number so

> **output**
> 622

I can already transform it into a decimal but I don't know how to find the highest zero number..
I only have the function to transform it into a decimal number.

```
def binaryToDecimal(n):
return int(n,2)


input = str(input(binaryToDecimal('1001101000110')))
```

Comment: what if there are multiple _most zeros_? for example 110001100011

Comment: Your last line of code is very wrong in many respects. Maybe you could explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solves the first part of your question;

```
s = '1001101000110'

def remover(s):
  res = s.split('1')
  m = max(res)
  newstr = s.replace(m, '')
  return newstr 

res = remover(s)
print(res)
```